# Reading a particular column from a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am currently trying to read in  a csv file for the purpose of creating a budget from a stament and I want to group similar items eg fuel etc. So id like to get the values from column E (aka column 5).  store these values in a list and pair them with cost and then group in to lumps eg fuel. So far for simply trying to read the column I have the following

```
temp=pd.read_csv("statement.csv",usecols=['columnE'])
print(temp)
```

and the following table:

[image]

Values removed for obvious reasons. However when I run this I get the error `Usecols do not match columns`, why is this? I assumed I would at least get a value even if it's not the right one.

Comment: Is there actually a column named 'columnE'?

Comment: Try `usecols=['Transaction Description']`.

Comment: hi Norrie yes transaction description. thanks martineau worked a treat. i guess the labels were not included

Answer (score 0):

Correct the column name to

```
temp=pd.read_csv("statement.csv",usecols=['Transaction Description'])
```

and try again